# open drop zone link on drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm new to coding and there is probably a simply solution to this problem:

I have created a drag and drop function (which works) but I want the drop zone to be connected to a link which I want to be opened when I drop the drag element on the drop zone. I only get it to work if I connect the link to the drag element but I need to have the link connected to the drop zone. So I guess there's something wrong with the javascript but I can't figure out what.

Thank you!

This is my code:

```
<div class="dragzone">
   <img src="img/circle.png" id="dragelement" height="100px"
        ondragstart="dragStart(event)"></div>
        
<div class="dropzone"> 
    <a href="world1.html"><img src="img/k3.mp4" height="350px"          ondragover=”allowDrop(event)"ondrop=”drop(event)"></a></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

<script>
function allowDrop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Url","");
}

function drop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    window.location=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Url");
} 
</script>
```